# Setting up continues Integration on TFS with GitLab as Repo

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, tfsbuild, tfs-2015, gitlab-ci

I need to configure CI pipeline in my TFS with source repo in GitLab, I have updated the Trigger section as below and checked in the code, but the build was not triggered, is there any configuration required in the GitLab repo? Please advice hot to achieve this.

[image]

Comment: Does it build correctly if you queue the build manually?

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT: Yes It build correctly when triggered a build manually.

Comment: I have the same error, and the log of the build triggered is automatically is:
Basic authentication requires a secure connection to the server. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Basic authentication requires a secure connection to the server gitlab my gitlab is exposed by http and we use VSTS on cloud to connect to GitLab like a external repo. if I trigger the build manually it work fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have changed the Poling interval to 180 seconds and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I would troubleshoot your problem by checking the following in this order:

- when triggering the build manually, does the source code downloading from the GitLab repository successfully work?
- if **yes**, then:

  - did you created and pushed the `develop` branch on the repository?
    You need to publish your locally created 'develop' branch on the remote repository, e.g. `>git push -u origin develop`
- if **no**, then there are issues on the "Services" entry you created on TFS for accessing your GitLab repository:

  - check whether you are using HTTPS in the URL;
  - to enable HTTPS access to your repository, remember to set a password on your GitLab account, then use that password along with your username (email address) on the "Services" endpoint set up on TFS;

p.s. also, check which 'Connection' is selected in the Repository section of your build definition: it should be the one pointing to your GitLab repo :-)